# Building portfolio website and I want to include my github link

Tags: reactjs

I am fairly newly to React. I am building my own portfolio website, and I have a link to my Github in my About component. I wonder how I should implement the code so users can click on the link and see my Github?

Below is where I am About component.

```
function About() {
    return (
        <div id="About" className="aboutsection">            
            <p className="aboutbodytext">
                I am a Software Engineer based out of San Francisco, CA with a background in the legal field. 
                {/* Skills I want to mention: research, strong communication    */}
            <br/>
            <br/>
            Interested in learning more?
            </p>
            <Link to="/PDFResume">Resume</Link> | <Link to="/linkedin">Linkedin</Link> | <Link to="/Github">Github</Link>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Also, please feel free to provide any feedbacks/suggestions you think are worthwhile knowing.

Thanks!

Comment: `<a href="https://github.com/username">GitHub</a>`?

Comment: Consider using CSS to add padding between paragraphs rather than `<br>` (which doesn't need the slash).

Comment: And list styling for the list of links. If it's a portfolio site I'd try to keep it clean; an advertisement for people digging around in the HTML. Not that I ever do that on portfolio sites when hiring somebody.